# Smartsheet - Get id of the row creator

Tags: smartsheet-api

I need to get the creator id, but request with `include=writerInfo` returns only email. The problem is that the user email can be changed and `createdBy` will change but `modifiedAt` will not change. Thus, I will need to get a list of users each time to determine the createdBy id of the row.

Is there a way to get the createdBy id when receiving a sheet with rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I'm seeing in the API docs, I don't believe it's possible to get `userId` at the row level in the results of a **Get Sheet** request.